# How do I specify the icon Android Wear uses on the watch face shortcut?

Tags: android, icons, wear-os, shortcut

I'm new to Android and Wear OS dev. Got an app up and running well pretty quickly; it launches and runs fine. The "fx" icon shown in the full round icon in the app display (yellow arrow) is the icon I designed and that works great. [image: App icon in app display]

I'm not creating a face but placing a shortcut to the app on the face by using the Android "Customize"|"Complication"|"App shortcut" mechanism -- it displays the same icon bitmap, but smaller, as a square, inside a dark gray circle button (yellow arrow on lower right of face).[image: The face with Strava and my "fx" app shortcut buttons]

I noticed that if I do the same thing with the Strava app (red arrow on app display, below, and left lower watch face, above) the Strava app displays a different icon on the face.[image: Strava app icon in app list (different from the shortcut button on the face)]

Can someone please point me to an example which handles this? I have a different icon image I'd like to use on the watch face. I know it's possible but haven't found the mechanism.

I'm guessing this has something to do with overriding the complication display, but since it's the OS that handles dragging the app icon shortcut to the watch face, I'm wondering if there's a special way to specify what I want to display on the face. Thanks!

Comment: Did you do the same procedure for the strava? Because, seems to me that your app was added as a image complication and the strava as a shortext complication... check this: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/data-sources#0

Comment: Both the Strava app and my fx app were placed on the face using the Customize|Complication mechanism and using App Shortcut|Choose App, so whatever Strava's doing to display its alternate graphic on the shortcut button, I need to do as well. Thanks for the link; I'll give that a try.